# Partial View uses different model than page it's contained in?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model, viewmodel, partial-views

I have a partial view in my main page that uses a different model than the main page uses.

In a nutshell what I have is a dropdown control on my main page that uses one model to populate its options. When an option is selected, I have a script that will post the selected option to another action method in the home controller. That method takes that value, and runs a db query dependent on that value. Then I put those results into a model and pass that model to my partial view. The partial view is rendered and then converted to HTML markup and passed back to the script in a JSON object. The script then writes the resulting view markup to a div in the main page.

My problem is that I get an error saying the partial view is looking for one model, when the model it's getting is the main page's model - not its own. Is there an easy way I can remedy this? I can't wrap both models in another model (view model) because the two models are passed through different action methods.

Here's the relevant code to hopefully assist:

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // Loaded when page first requested. Displays a dropdown with all
    // distinct sampling events.
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        // Set page title
        ViewBag.Title = "Sample Tracker Tool";
        // Calculate range filter for samples
        DateTime nineMonthsAgo = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-270);

        // Retrieve sampling events within filter range
        var context = new EDMS_Entities();
        var resultSet = (from samplingEvents in context.EDMS_SAMPLES
                         where samplingEvents.RECORD_CREATED_DATE >= nineMonthsAgo
                         orderby samplingEvents.SAMPLING_EVENT
                         select samplingEvents.SAMPLING_EVENT).Distinct();

        // Create viewmodel for sampling events dropdown use
        var viewModel = new SamplingEventsVM();
        viewModel.SamplingEvents = new SelectList(resultSet);

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    // When the selected sampling event is changed, jQuery posts the selected value
    // to this method. The selected value is used to return all samples for the
    // selected sampling event.
    public ActionResult RetrieveSamples(string samplingEvent)
    {
        // This currently just returns the selected sampling event
        // TODO: Use sampling event to retrieve all samples and construct a list of
        // Sample objects for the selected sampling event. These samples will be used
        // to display the sample's list of analytes.

        // Retrieve samples for selected sampling event
        // **Samples query in progress...**
        // TODO: Finish constructing the full query
        var context = new EDMS_Entities();
        var resultSet = from samples in context.EDMS_SAMPLES
                        join stations in context.EDMS_SAMPLE_STATIONS on samples.STATION_SEQ equals stations.STATION_SEQ
                        where samples.SAMPLING_EVENT == samplingEvent
                        select new { samples.SAMPLE_ID, stations.STATION_ID, samples.COLLECTION_DATE, samples.COMMENTS };

        // Assign results to model objects and add resulting model objects to the ObservableCollection instance "sampleResults"
        ObservableCollection<Sample> sampleResults = new ObservableCollection<Sample>();
        foreach(var row in resultSet)
        {
            var newSample = new Sample(row.SAMPLE_ID, row.STATION_ID, row.COLLECTION_DATE, row.COMMENTS);
            sampleResults.Add(newSample);
        }

        // Pass sample objects to partial view and parse HTML markup from rendered partial view
        var partialViewHtml = RenderViewToString(this.ControllerContext, "~/Views/Home/RetrieveSamples.cshtml", sampleResults);

        // Add partial view HTML markup to new JsonResult object
        JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
        result.Data = partialViewHtml;

        return result;
    }

    // Convert partial view to HTML string
    private string RenderViewToString(ControllerContext context, string viewName, object model)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(viewName))
        {
            viewName = context.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
        }

        var viewData = new ViewDataDictionary(model);

        using (var writer = new StringWriter())
        {
            var viewResult = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(context, viewName);
            var viewContext = new ViewContext(context, viewResult.View, viewData, new TempDataDictionary(), writer);
            viewResult.View.Render(viewContext, writer);

            return writer.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

**Main View**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    @using SampleTracking.Models.ViewModels;
    @model SamplingEventsVM
    <head>
        <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/CustomScripts.js"></script>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <span id="SamplingEventDiv">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedSamplingEvent, Model.SamplingEvents, new { @id = "SamplingEventSelection" })
        </span>
        <div id="SamplingEventDetails">
            @Html.Partial("~/Views/Home/RetrieveSamples.cshtml")
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Partial View**

```
@using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
@using SampleTracking.Models.ViewModels;
@model ObservableCollection<Sample>
<div id="SamplingEventDetails">
    @foreach (var sample in Model)
    {
        <div>sample.SampleID</div>
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried...

```
Html.Partial("~/Views/Home/RetrieveSamples.cshtml",new SomeModel())
```

Comment: I have not, but I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Actually now that I think of it, I don't think that'll solve my problem. That line is still in the main view, so I'd have to get the model there somehow, which is my problem.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I resolved this -- turns out I really didn't need the Html.Partial since my script fetches the rendered view as HTML anyway. The helper method was unnecessary.